Animation Movie Series aired in Cartoon Network about Car Racing
I remember this series of movies where there were racers wearing white jackets and they wait for a portal to open which takes these racers to a different world and they have to complete the race. 
Many obstacles in their path and finally the main racers would reach a different world at end of one race (while others come back) where he finds his dad all wearing white racing suites. 
I searched for it but I found Hot Wheels but in HW his father was found by all his friends together. 
While in what I was searching at the end of race the hero alone will find his dad which would be a surprise in the story line. 
They will also use Cello Charges to power up their car which gives them varied strengths.
Could you please help me to identify this Series/Movie?

There are multiple HW series. Could be that you're looking for one of the other HW series.

Based on this M&TV Question this is likely the...
Hot Wheels: AcceleRacers series




Hot Wheels: AcceleRacers is an animated series of movies by Mattel. It is computer-animated, produced by Mainframe Entertainment out of Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada, which also produced ReBoot and distributed by Warner Bros. Available on DVD and VHS, it has also been shown on Cartoon Network.
The show takes Mattel's Hot Wheels toy cars and puts them in a ReBoot-like situation, with racing somewhat reminiscent of Tron. This is a sequel series to Hot Wheels World Race. Both shows take place in California.
Wikipedia


There are four DVDs in the series. They constitute one continuous story. In story order they are:

Ignition (60 min)
The Speed of Silence (60 min)
Breaking Point (60 min)
The Ultimate Race (60 min)


The final film ends in one of the Silencerz revealing himself to be none other than Vert's father, and the series ends in a cliffhanger, with Vert's father telling Vert, "Son, we need to talk".

